# Access Variable Variable in ForEach From Outside Class

Tags: php, class, variables, foreach, variable-variables

I have a class that for the sake of example to make it easier to understand, takes an associative array, loops over it and assigns a variable name, based on key, and assigns it the value.
This works fine in the class:

```
class showItems {

  static public function list(){
    foreach ($list as $name => $value) {
      $$name = $value;
    }
    // This works here
    echo $title; // This is the variable I want Which is being set in the foreach.
    break;

  }

}
```

The above class works fine, and $title can be echo'd.
However, accessing that variable from outside of the class is where I don't have any luck. I've tried all types of processes I can think of.

```
$showItems = new showItems();
$showItems::list();

// Cannot grasp what I need to do here to echo the value I want.
$showItems::list()->$title; // This returns "Trying to get property of non-object"

?>
```

Comment: What does function `showItems` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't `echo` inside your `list` method.
2. You can reach your `static` `list` method through your `class` like this: `showItems::list()`
3. You are not passing a parameter to your `list` method, which is highly strange, as you have stated that it

> takes an associative array

1. Your `$list` seems to be uninitialized inside your `list` method.
2. No need to instantiate your `class` if you only want to call a `static` method.
3. It is unclear what you are trying to do, so please, rephrase your question and write a comment to this post, so I will edit my answer to help you further.

Comment: It's quite clear, inside the foreach loop running inside the class, I can echo $title, so I know it's working, don't worry about the rest of the code. However - how do I actually retrieve that $title variable from outside of the class?

Comment: You can create a static member called $title inside your showItems class and create a getter for it. However, if something seemingly "works", that is not necessarily correct.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like `$TestItems=new testItems()` then `TestItems->list()` and make the list function `return $title`.